# Generic term for CRS axes?

Tags: coordinate-system, terminology

We're making a light web front to a database, and I saw this in a test screenshot:

[image: XY values in lat long boxes]

Despite those coordinates being nowhere near North America, the "latitude/longitude" label for those coordinates really ruffled my jimmies. This got me wondering if there is a generic yet unambiguous term for each axis.

The first idea that came up was to just change the labels to <s>X and Y</s> Easting and Northing, but my understanding is those are terms used specifically for Cartesian coordinates. If the CRS was EPSG:4269, then the labels we have now would be correct.

We can probably derive the proper axes labels from the CRS, but I thought I'd ask if there's an accepted generic term (other than "value that increments along the north axis") to just sidestep the issue.

Comment: "X" and "Y" are valid **if** you present them in the correct order (Latitude is Y).

Comment: @Vince Only if you're using a CRS that specifies that. There are systems that label the Northing as X and Easting as Y. Mintx, why not check the CRS type and change the labels to match?

Comment: UTM **is** a Cartesian coordinate system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're seeking generic terms, which are independent of the shape of the coordinate reference surface (planar or spheroidal) for coordinate axes, you're out of luck.

For **planar** reference surfaces, the terms are *northings* and *eastings* (or in very rare cases, southings and westings).

For **spheroidal** reference surfaces, the terms are *latitude* and *longitude* (for N-S and E-W angular values, respectively).

What is *not* consistent, because it depends on the application context or the discipline being served, is the *order;* it can be N,E *or* E,N, and lat,lon *or* lon,lat.

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion is to go with your "if we have to" concept at the end, and not hard-code those into the UI. Instead, make the Coordinate system a combo-box at the top of that part of the UI, and then generate whatever the axes are from the user's selection in that combo-box.

If that is really an input box and the CRS terms are going to change fairly often (e.g. lon / lat and northing / easting), its likely that the user will get confused at some point. Applying sanity checks on the values (where possible) seems like a good investment in time.

Note that there are CRS that have more than two axes, although it isn't clear if that will affect your implementation.